# Can I get a virus on Android 4.4.2 by clicking "no thanks" on one of those virus browser pop-ups?

Tags: security, antivirus

I opened a link using the built-in facebook browser yesterday, and pop-ups on the website kept asking me if I wanted to install some anti-virus and they had two options: No thanks and OK.  Normally I press the back button because I'm wary of clicking anything, but this time I clicked "Cancel."

I've noticed some weird behavior with my phone freezing this morning and now I'm paranoid.  Could have clicking "Cancel" actually installed something?  Was the message box option spoofed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's hard to know. Install avast anti-virus from google play and it will show any viruses (if there are any). But that 'Message Box' shouldn't have appeared, so that means either Facebook was hacked or you were using a fake Facebook app/page. Clicking 'No Thanks' on a webpage can't install anything unless you already have a virus on your Android. You should be safe if you were using the genuine Facebook app/page and that `Settings>Security>Unknown Sources` was unchecked.

Comment: I was using the genuine facebook app, which now has its own built-in browser for when you click on links in facebook posts.

Are you really positive that clicking a pop-up message box can't install anything?

Comment: I can also confirm that i have `Settings>Security>Unknown Sources` unchecked!

Comment: The only way anything could be installed is by installing it from the Google play store, A apk (Unknown sources HAS to be enabled, ADB). But there is one way in which something can happen: If you have a application installed on your android, a link can open it and start a action (Such as using loads of RAM). Do you remember what it said in the message box?

Comment: And clicking 'No Thanks' can open a link but definately not install anything

Comment: Finally found it again:  `"The page at "http://quickscanner.co" says: === Android Warning === Is your Android browser outdated?  Tap 'OK' to download the latest now!"`  And there are two options: Cancel and OK.  I clicked Cancel.

Comment: Ok then if you dont have any suspicious apps then you are 100% clean no need to be paranoid! I still reccomend installing avast because it will stop things like this happening again!

Comment: Please check this answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I installed Look Out.